# Parsing S3 URI into bucket and key in Go

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

There doesn't seem to be a function in the official AWS Go SDK that'll parse an `s3://` style URI-like string (i.e. `s3://mybucket/some/place/on/there.gz`) and provide things like the bucket and key. The Java SDK [has such a function](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.java). Am I missing an obvious reason why the Go SDK does not?

This question is about maintaining compatibility. An SDK function provides a clear authority on how to properly parse S3 addresses and deters worry over subtle cases that `url.Parse()` and ilk may miss.

Comment: I can't really comment on why the library does not do this, but there are a lot of little simple things in Go that seem like there should be functions for, yet there are none (see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks). I believe that such things are idiomatic in Go itself to keep the standard libraries slim.  As to the library though, this does seem like it is something that should be in there. Maybe submit a pull request? Which library specifically are you using?

Comment: That's just a single line of code why do you need the library to this anyway?

Comment: This is a question for the AWS SDK devs, not SO.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki While I agree with you in this instance (with S3 because they are unlikely to break things), in general it makes sense to have a library handle this sort of thing in case they make incompatible changes to the structure. Users doing simple string manipulation get burned, while users using the library methods get an update and all is well.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear if they change the S3 URL structure or the fundamental addressing of S3 objects, everything using S3 will go to hell in a bobsled.

Comment: @Adrian hence why my comment was directed to the general case

Comment: What is "the general case"? All string manipulation? This seems like something where there is no general case and certainly no universally-applicable logic.

Comment: @Adrian general case being a service provides e.g. a URL in a specific form, then for some reason has to make breaking changes to that structure. Everyone who rolled their own solution breaks, whereas if there was a library function to parse whatever needed info, those users would just update and move on.

Comment: Having a library do all your stuffs is always awesome but this specific case is way too simple. I think if you write one function and test it one or two times then there are like no chances of breaking. I agree with @Adrian completely on this

Comment: @RayfenWindspear gets it. I've updated the question in an attempt to be clearer.

Answer (score 14):

Though only the AWS devs can answer the actual question (why isn't this included in the SDK), there is the simple answer: S3 URLs are URLs, and you can use `net/url` to parse them:

```
u,_ := url.Parse("s3://mybucket/some/place/on/there.gz")
fmt.Printf("proto: %q, bucket: %q, key: %q", u.Scheme, u.Host, u.Path)
```

[Playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/gpcVYuU3fZ)

Comment: **Warning**: If you do this, note that it will give you a slash (/) character at the start of the Path/Key.

If you try to use some or all of the `u.Path` value as a prefix in a `ListObjectsV2` API call later it will **fail** because of that slash; you must remove it before sending the string back to AWS.